# Array.push only pushing a single value instead of all of them in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

I have declared a simple array in my JavaScript and I'm trying to push values from another array that has a dictionary inside it. But only the first value is getting pushed and not the rest of them.

```
<script>

complist = []
var testjs = [{'issuancedte': 'Finance', 'totalcomp': 1}, {'issuancedte': 'AnotherOne', 'totalcomp': 5}]

for (opt in testjs)
   if ((adm_section_array.includes(testjs[opt].issuancedte)))
     $('#data').append('<tr><td>' + testjs[opt].issuancedte + '</td><td>' + testjs[opt].totalcomp + '</td></tr>')
     complist.push(testjs[opt].totalcomp);

</script>
```

So, from the code above I should be getting:

```
complist = [1, 5]
```

but instead I'm only getting:

```
complist = [1]
```

For some completely unknown reasons, if I place the .push line above the one where I'm appending data to a form, the complist is made as it should be but the table doesn't get appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be written like this,

```
if ((adm_section_array.includes(testjs[opt].issuancedte))) {
     $('#data').append('<tr><td>' + testjs[opt].issuancedte + '</td><td>' + testjs[opt].totalcomp + '</td></tr>')
     complist.push(testjs[opt].totalcomp);
}
```

Notice the curly braces after if block.

Comment: Wow, rookie mistake, shouldn't be making that. Thank you for pointing it out, it's working now!

Comment: If this answer solves the problem please check it as resolved.

Comment: Will do, have to wait 10 minutes before I can do it.